# boost::interprocess_exception - library_error exception when creating shared_memory_object

Tags: c++, exception, boost, interprocess

In some rare cases (in fact on a single client's computer) code below throws an exception "**library_error**":

```
namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;
ipc::shared_memory_object m_shm;
...
bool initAsServer(size_t sharedMemSize)
{
    ipc::permissions perm;
    perm.set_unrestricted();

    try
    {
        m_shm = ipc::shared_memory_object(
            ipc::create_only,
            CNameGenHelper::genUniqueNameUtf8().c_str(), // static std::string genUniqueNameUtf8()
            ipc::read_write, perm);
    }
    catch(const ipc::interprocess_exception& ex)
    {
        logError("failed with exception \"%s\"", ex.what());
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

In log file:
**[ERR]     failed with exception "boost::interprocess_exception::library_error"**

Boost v1.58, platform win32, vs13.

---

I'll be very grateful if you help me in solving this problem. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you checking if the shared memory segment already exists in the system ?

Comment: No, this is not necessary since the function CNameGenHelper::genUniqueNameUtf8() generates a unique name based on the GUID. I added to the log file getting error codes via  ex.get_error_code() and ex.get_native_error() for additional exception information. Now I wating for log files from client side... Thank you for your interest in this issue!

Comment: for updated line in catch:
logError("failed with exception \"%s\", error %d, native error %d", ex.what(), ex.get_error_code(), ex.get_native_error());
---
In log file: [ERR] failed with exception "boost::interprocess_exception::library_error", error 1, native error 0.
---
error 1 - system_error (from enum error_code_t)
Help me please...

Comment: Note: I'm trying to to allocate a relatively small amount of memory, only ~8 MB.

Comment: Why dont you step through a debugger in the function ? That would surely help you find the code where its throwing the exception.

Comment: I can not use the debugger on the client (customer) computer.

Answer (score 4):

Reason of problem is events with Event ID = "6005" and source name is "EventLog" in "System" Windows log.
[Event Viewer - Windows Logs - System.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y0sN.png)
If the system log does not contain at least one such event, then method *boost::interprocess::winapi::get_last_bootup_time()* returns *false* and *boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::windows_bootstamp* constructor *throws exception*.
(define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_HAS_KERNEL_BOOTTIME is used).

So it seems that it is enough to clear the "System" windows event log and any application that uses the Boost shared memory will stop working.

What a terrible logic: use the contents of the windows event log.
It seems this boost ipc implementation bug that has not yet been fixed (boost_1_61_0).

My temporary workaround for this case (w/o reboot of computer):

```
bool fixBoostIpcSharedMem6005issue() const
{
    bool result = false;

    HANDLE hEventLog = ::RegisterEventSourceA(NULL, "EventLog");
    if(hEventLog)
    {
        const char* msg = "simple boost shared memory fix for 6005";

        if(::ReportEventA(hEventLog, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 6005, NULL, 1, 0, &msg, NULL))
            result = true;

        ::DeregisterEventSource(hEventLog);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Use it and try to use ipc::shared_memory_object again :)

Answer (score 1):

Many detailed explanations about by the problem, by one of the authors of the library: [Boost interprocess: Getting boot-up time is unreliable on Windows](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/boost-developers-archive/2YGlY6Jr-dE) and here: [Interprocess get_last_bootup_time use of Event Log on Windows is completely unreliable](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/11480)

Apparently, a reliable solution is to define the preprocessor constant BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_PATH to a function call, which always returns the same directory path as a string, once the machine is booted. For example by formatting the update time-stamp of a file, written to at start-up.

Answer (score 1):

You can #define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_BOOTSTAMP_IS_SESSION_MANAGER_BASED or BOOST_INTERPROCESS_BOOTSTAMP_IS_LASTBOOTUPTIME to switch to either registry or WMI based boot time detection. 
Alternatively, you can use BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_PATH, but it's kind of useless on Windows since it uses hardcoded path. BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_FUNC is much better option since it lets you define a function that returns path to the shared directory.