# Boost shared memory can't be initialized

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

Hi and there is my issue:

I'm trying to create a shared memory segment using this code snippet:

```
      #include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
      using namespace boost::interprocess;

      ...   

      shared_memory_object::remove("MyShareMem");
      try {

        managed_shared_memory segment_(create_only,
                                       "MyShareMem",
                                       10 * 1024 * 1024);
        ...
      }
      catch (interprocess_exception &ex) {
        std::cout << "Exception: "<< ex.what() << std::endl;
      }
```

But then I've got an exception:

`Exception: boost::interprocess::intermodule_singleton initialization failed`

I am rather at a loss of what to do and how to fix the issue.

Is there any ideas how to deal with this?

---

UPDATED:

I found solution here
[boost::interprocess_exception - library_error exception when creating shared_memory_object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045857/boostinterprocess-exception-library-error-exception-when-creating-shared-mem)

It's a bit weird, but here boost relies on Windows Event Logger. And if there is no event with ID = 6005. It throws an exception.

The code snippet from the boost 1.62.0 [win32_api.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/boost/interprocess/detail/win32_api.hpp)

```
//Obtains the bootup time from the System Event Log,
//event ID == 6005 (event log started).
//Adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427356.aspx
inline bool get_last_bootup_time(std::string &stamp)
{
   const char *source_name = "System";
   const char *provider_name = "EventLog";
   const unsigned short event_id = 6005u;
```

The solution was just to add the event 6005 and all work again fine.

Comment: Have you tried allocating a smaller portion?

Comment: Yes, I've just tried for 1024 bytes and still it doesn't work. For sure the problem will gone after restarting of my PC, but I would rather find a better solution :)

Comment: the exception comes from here [intermodule_singleton_common](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/interprocess/detail/intermodule_singleton_common.hpp)

Comment: I found similar bug in boost [Ticket #12232]{https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12232}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the explanation here, why the windows system event logger is used. From the boost docs [Shared memory emulation folder](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/interprocess/acknowledgements_notes.html#interprocess.acknowledgements_notes.notes_windows.notes_windows_shm_folder)

> Shared memory (shared_memory_object) is implemented in windows using
>   memory mapped files, placed in a shared directory in the shared
>   documents folder
>   (SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell
>   Folders\Common AppData). This directory name is the last bootup time
>   obtained via COM calls (if
>   BOOST_INTERPROCESS_BOOTSTAMP_IS_LASTBOOTUPTIME) defined or **searching
>   the system log for a startup event (the default implementation), so
>   that each bootup shared memory is created in a new folder obtaining
>   kernel persistence shared memory**.
>
> If using BOOST_INTERPROCESS_BOOTSTAMP_IS_LASTBOOTUPTIME, due to COM
>   implementation related errors, in Boost 1.48 & Boost 1.49 the
>   bootup-time folder was dumped and files were directly created in
>   shared documents folder, reverting to filesystem persistence shared
>   memory. Boost 1.50 fixed those issues and recovered bootup time
>   directory and kernel persistence. If you need to reproduce Boost 1.48
>   & Boost 1.49 behaviour to communicate with applications compiled with
>   that version, comment #define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_HAS_KERNEL_BOOTTIME
>   directive in the Windows configuration part of
>   boost/interprocess/detail/workaround.hpp.
>
> If using the default implementation,
>   (BOOST_INTERPROCESS_BOOTSTAMP_IS_LASTBOOTUPTIME undefined) and the
>   Startup Event is not found, this might be due to some buggy software
>   that floods or erases the event log.
>
> In any error case (shared documents folder is not defined or bootup
>   time could not be obtained, the library throws an error. You still can
>   use Boost.Interprocess definining your own directory as the shared
>   directory. **Just define BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_PATH when using
>   the library and that path will be used to place shared memory files**.

And also there you can find a better solution of the issue. You just need to set your own folder where to store boost shared memory files by defining **BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_PATH**. And you won't be dependent on the windows event logger.

Answer (score 1):

Too late comment but anyway

BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_PATH will hardcode the path which is not in best practices list.
Much better way is to define **BOOST_INTERPROCESS_SHARED_DIR_FUNC** and implement

```
void get_shared_dir(std::string& shared_dir)
{
    // get dir path from environment variable for instance
}
```